# How to Read 醤玉子?

Tags: pronunciation, readings

I know that 玉子 is read "tamago".  I also know that 醤油 is read "shouyu".  I can imagine that 醤玉子 refers to the boiled egg that is submerged in soy sauce.  How do you read it though?  I assume it's read "shoutamago".

I tried entering it into jisho.org, and it says "hishio tamago".  This translation, however, is not a direct translation of 醤玉子.  It's more of a translation of 醤 and 玉子 stuck together.

In English, we can make words up and its meaning can be inferred from the parts.  An example would be soy-egg.  That only works, since there's only one way to spell and pronounce soy and egg.  I can infer the meaning of 醤玉子, which I hope I understood correctly, but I am not quite sure how to go about reading these agglomerations.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is one pronunciation that Japanese customers might ask about too. What is your source?

Comment: @user27280 I've since lost the source image containing 醤玉子, but [this image](https://resources.matcha-jp.com/resize/720x2000/2018/02/22-48782.jpeg) has 肉醤油.  Similarly, jisho.org cannot directly translate 肉醤油, as a whole, but it can translate 肉 and 醤油 as "niku" and "shouyu".  Would it be pronounced "nikushouyu"?

Comment: Usually it would be assumed to be にくじょうゆ (using rendaku), but にくしょうゆ is not unacceptable (try typing it into IME). I don't think that I can answer your original question about 醤玉子 with much certainty without knowing more.

Comment: I don't see anything on Jisho to suggest that 醤玉子 should be read ひしおたまご. It simply does not appear in the database, so the two items were displayed side-by-side, but with no indication that it recognized it as a word.

Comment: Are you sure you saw just 醤玉子 and not, say, XO醤玉子?

Comment: If you're referring to soy sauce flavoured eggs as served with ramen, those are usually known as 味付け玉子 and not the word that you imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

醤玉子 is not a word people know, which means no one knows its correct meaning or reading. If this is not your own made-up word, then you probably misread something, as droooze pointed out. Unsurprisingly, you cannot get anything useful if you put an entirely new word/phrase to Google or a dictionary site.

Also note that 醤 and 醤油 mean two very difficult things, just as "soy" and "soy sauce" are different in English. 醤 by itself means something like "(spicy/salty) fermented paste", and it [appears in the names of various Asian seasoning materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%86%AC). Generally speaking, 醤 is read "ジャン" if it's part of the name of foreign paste (e.g., 豆板醤 = トウバンジャン, 苦椒醬 = コチュジャン).

If I somehow had to assume 醤玉子 *is* a correct word and had to guess its meaning, I would probably think it's a rare non-Japanese dish which has nothing to do with 醤油. This is because, as a native speaker, I know Japanese better than any other languages and I know 醤玉子 is not a traditional Japanese dish. As for the reading, it's difficult to guess, but しょうたまご, ひしおたまご and じゃんたまご seem equally possible to me.